# CVE-2021-44906 Prototype Pollution in minimist

Tags: dependabot, minimist

Github dependabot found potential security vulnerabilities in My dependencies.

- Minimist <=1.2.5 is vulnerable to Prototype Pollution via file index.js, function setKey() (lines 69-95).

I don't know how to fix it. What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Origin: https://github.com/substack/minimist/issues/164

Fix Resolution: `minimist - 1.2.6`

Install npm-force-resolutions:

```
npx npm-force-resolutions
```

then Add field resolutions with the dependency version you want to fix to your `package.json` file. It modifies `package-lock.json` to force the installation of a specific version of a transitive dependency.

```
"resolutions": {
    "minimist": "1.2.6"
}
```

Comment: origin: https://github.com/substack/minimist/issues/164

Comment: I had to run `npx npm-force-resolutions` after modifying package.json

Comment: You can find some more background information on this [here](https://dev.to/rembrandtreyes/ahhhh-cves-266e) - what are resolutions and why do you need them?

Comment: See also here: [minimist-vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176146/minimist-vulnerability)