# Minimist vulnerability

Tags: npm, ember.js, ember-cli, minimist

We are facing critical vulnerability in minimist which is added as transitive dependency.

```
+-- ember-cli@3.24.0
| +-- bower-config@1.4.3
| | `-- minimist@0.2.1
```

We tried to resolve this using couple of methods recommended on multiple forums but still no luck. Any pointers will help.

**Method 1 Resolutions**

Changes in package.json file

```
  "scripts": {    
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  }
  
  "resolutions": {
    "minimist": "1.2.6"
}
```

**Method 2 Overrides**

```
 "overrides": {
    "ember-cli": {
      "bower-config": {
        "minimist": "1.2.6"
      }
    }
 }
```

> NPM Version 8.1.2

Comment: Stupid suggestions, but have you tried to: 1) upgrade ember? 2) remove the bower? (it's kinda under the deprecation process in ember nowadays)

Comment: Thanks for reply @AndreyStukalin , we are tried with 3.28.0(LTS) but thats not resolving either , How can I manually remove bower from ember-cli

Comment: Bower is still available internally in Ember CLI for a bit longer but you have no security risk if you aren’t using bower, as the dependency that is being flagged is never used in a production context

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem(with older ember but still). For `yarn` something like this did the trick:

```json
"resolutions": {
  "ember-cli/bower-config/minimist": "1.2.6"
}
```

Equivalent in npm would be be [overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) field available from npm 8.3.0.
It should look something like this:

```json
"overrides": {
  "minimist": "1.2.6"
}
```

or

```json
"overrides": {
  "ember-cli": {
    "bower-config": {
      "minimist": "1.2.6"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs +1 , Yes I was able to achieve this using similar approach however.  forgot to update answer. Will update detailed answer

Comment: See also here: [cve-2021-44906-prototype-pollution-in-minimist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71569904/cve-2021-44906-prototype-pollution-in-minimist)

Comment: `"overrides": {
  "minimist": "1.2.6"
}` did the trick for me. Thank you! You saved our day.